# JQuery height and units

Tags: jquery, units-of-measurement

I know that `height()` method of jquery returns a number unitless...
How can i be sure that this number is in the unit i want?

I want to work with centimeter cm any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the unit returned by height() is **pixels**.

converting that to cm might be difficult, as that depends on the user's monitor, size of pixels, etc.

question, why in gods name do you want cm?

Comment: Wrong! height() returns unitless height. For example, if height is 20cm, height() will return 20, which is *not* height in pixels!

Comment: Wrong! in the United States, height() will return 7.87, because we use inches here.

Comment: mkoryak is right here. The documentation itself says: "The difference between .css('height') and .height() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400)". In other words, .height() contains no units in its value and is instead explicitly stated to be pixels.

Comment: @dave this has not been my experience. "Unitless" does not mean Pixels, it means without suffix (so it can be used for mathematical purposes). If height() is asked for on an element defined by % then in 'certain circumstances' eg pre loading on screen the unitless height returned will be css %, but without the % suffix. so "50" is actually 50%.

Answer (score 5):

```
var div = $("<div></div>").css("height","1cm");

$("body").prepend(div);

var height = div.height();

div.remove();

alert(height);
```

I know it is stupid solution, but how about this? :D
For me usually returns 38px == 1cm

Do you think it's OK?

Comment: It's a stupid solution, you're right. Such stupid that has solved my problem. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

height returns height in pixels. Unfortunately centimeters is going to be very difficult for you to work with. Monitors all have different pixel densities, and javascript does not have a way to know this pixel density. You'll have to estimate how many pixels average a centimeter and convert from there.

Average pixel density would have anywhere from 100-130px in a centimeter, as you can tell this is a pretty wide range.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an invisible div with a known size and then use. width() and divide by the known size to get the ratio.